# Use a set of routes to operate upon in app.all() function of node express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a list of routes in my express application.
I need to perform a particular action on some of these routes.

For eg :

```
app.get('/xyz', file.xyz);

app.post('/xyz1', file.xyz1);

app.post('/xyz2', file.xyz2);

app.post('/xyz3', file.xyz3);

app.post('/xyz4', file.xyz4);
```

Now I want to perform similar action for '/xyz2' and '/xyz3' routes.
I came across through:

```
app.all('*', function (request, response, next) {
  //some action here
  next();
});
```

I would need to pass something like :

```
app.all(['/xyz2','/xyz3'], function (request, response, next) {
  //some action here
  next();
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your query here?

Answer (score 0):

Express routes can be matched using regex.

Try this:

```
app.all(/\/xyz[23]/, function (request, response, next) {
  //some action here
  next();
});
```